# Rails: Manipulate active record object without saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an `ActiveRecord` object that I want to manipulate without saving to the database. When I try to manipulate it using setters, it turns into an array and I can't call anymore `ActiveRecord methods` on it anymore. Is there a way to prevent against this.

Here is my situation:

I have a model `Server`, and I want to create a method that returns all `Server` records, sets a `attribute` called `imported` to `false`, then returns the `ActiveRecord` list of all `Servers` with their newly updated `imported` attribute, all without changing the database.

Here is what I have

```
def servers_imported
  servers = Servers.all
  servers.each do |server|
    server.imported = false
  end
  servers
end
```

My solution effectively changes the `imported` attributes of all the `Servers` without actually saving this change to the database. However, the return value `servers` is an `array` and not an `ActiveRecord` object. I need it to be an `ActiveRecord` object because I need to use additional methods.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `servers = Server.all` you get an array of active record objects. You iterate this collection and return this array. The `servers` variable is a collection all the time. If you need to use additional methods on active record objects you need iterate it again.

```
def servers_imported
  servers = Servers.all
  servers.each do |server|
    server.imported = false
  end
  servers
end

my_servers = servers_imported
my_servers.each do |server|
  server.my_pretty_method
end
```